# Raspberry Pi game crashes out when button is pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have this Python program which I'm running on Raspberry Pi:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from random import randint

# Setup GPIO pins
# Set the BCM mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Outputs
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)

# Ensure all LED's are off
GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)

# Inputs
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

global player
player = 0

# Setup the callback functions
def rock(channel):
    global player
    player = 1 # magic number 1 = rock, pin 12

def paper(channel):
    global player
    player = 2 # magic number 2 = paper, pin 16

def scissors(channel):
      global player
      player = 3 # magic number 3 = scissors, pin 21

def quit_game(channel):
    GPIO.cleanup()
    exit() # pin 20, immediate exit of game

# Add event detection and callback assignments
GPIO.add_event_detect(12, GPIO.RISING, callback=rock)
GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.RISING, callback=paper)
GPIO.add_event_detect(21, GPIO.RISING, callback=scissors)
GPIO.add_event_detect(20, GPIO.RISING, callback=quit_game)

# Computer random pick
computer = randint(1, 3)

while True:

    if player == computer:
        # This is a tie condition
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(5)
        GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
        player = 0
    elif player == 1:
        if computer == 2:
            # Player loses, paper covers rock
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
            print "Player = rock, Computer = paper\n"
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
            player = 0
        else:
            # Player wins, rock dulls paper
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
            print "Player = rock, Computer = scissors\n"
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
            player = 0
    elif player == 2:
        if computer == 3:
            # Player loses, scissors cut paper
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
            print "Player = paper, Computer = scissors\n"
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
            player = 0
        else:
            # Player wins, paper covers rock
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
            print "Player = paper, Computer = rock\n"
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
            player = 0
    elif player == 3:
        if computer == 1:
            # Player loses, rock dulls scissors
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
            print "Player = scissors, Computer  = rock\n"
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
            player = 0
        else:
            # Player wins, scissors cut paper
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
            print "Player = scissors, Computer = paper\n"
            time.sleep(5)
            GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
            player = 0

    # Another random pick for the computer
    computer = randint(1, 3)
```

It is a rock, paper, scissors game which is to be played on a circuit created on a breadboard. I built the circuit based on this diagram:

[image: Diagram of circuit for Rock, Paper, Scissors game]

This is an image of the actual circuit I built:

[image: Actual circuit for Rock, Paper, Scissors game]

When I run the program on my Raspbery Pi, it starts without issue but if I press a button the program crashes. I can see that the print statement is printed to the console before the application crashes. E.g. `Player = rock, Computer = paper`. This should happen after the LED switches on but the LED never lights up.

Can anybody suggest possible courses of investigation?

**Update**

OK, the buttons were supposed to be connected to pins 12, 16, 20 and 21 but were actually connected to GND, 20, 21 and nothing. Once I corrected that the program stopped crashing. The issue still seems to exist though.

I've now added `print "Quit game"` to my `quit` function and noticed that it seems to get called no matter which buttin I press:

```
def quit(channel):
    print "Quit game"
    GPIO.cleanup()
    exit() # pin 20, immediate exit of game

$ python rock_paper_scissors/prs_with_LEDs_and_switches.py 
Player = scissors, Computer = rock
Quit game
```

Comment: Can you define "crashes"? Are you getting a Python traceback? A segmentation fault? Something else? Please include any specific error messages in your question.

Comment: Not getting any errors or faults. This is all I get:

    `pi@raspberrypi:~/AI $ python rock_paper_scissors/prs_with_LEDs_and_switches.py 
    Player = scissors, Computer = paper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my breadboard. When I created the circuit on a new one there was no issue.